# Wildcard search in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

Is wildcard search possible in Gmail?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Not in general, no.

The Gmail search functionality works based on what I would describe as *tokens*.  A token is any sequence of alphanumeric characters separated by a space or by other non-alphanumeric characters such as underscore, full stop (period), "@", dash, etc..  So in peter.ford23@example.com there are 4 tokens: "peter", "ford23", "example" and "com".

Wildcards **within** tokens do not work.  Wildcards **outside of** tokens are unnecessary and misleading.

Imagine you wish to find messages from peter.ford23@example.com and tried these examples:

```
from:(pete*)
```

... would not work

```
from:(ford23@*)
```

... would work, but is misleading.  It is no different from searching for "from:ford23".

If you thought that Gmail was checking for the "@" symbol immediately after "ford23", you could try this instead ...

```
from:(peter@*)
```

... should not work, but does!

`

One example given in another answer is

```
subject:(jefferson-*)
```

... but again, Gmail is inadvertently misleading us.  The dash and asterisk characters have no effect.  (You can remove them and then remove the brackets too.  It's the same as searching for "subject:jefferson".)  It *would* return an email with subject "meeting with jefferson.jones".

```
subject:(jefferso*)
```

... would **not** return an email with subject "jefferson-school"

```
subject:(jefferso*-*)
```

... would **not** return an email with subject "jefferson-school"

`

There has been a suggestion that **Perl regex** can be used.  I will not address that suggestion here, except to repeat that wildcards **within** tokens do not work (even using Perl syntax).  And wildcards **outside of** tokens are unnecessary and misleading.

`

Disclaimer: For the sake of brevity I have used uncertainty-free language above. But I do not work for Google and I am not 100% sure of every claim in this answer.  I *do* believe it is one of the best answers so far though.  Google's own [Gmail search operators help page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) doesn't mention wildcards.

Comment: I'm not sure how I'm supposed to interpret "`from:(ford23@*)` would work, but is misleading" combined with "`from:(peter@*)` should not work, but does". Are you basically saying that you have no idea why those are interpreted differently? Or are those interpreted the same? Or are you trying to suggest that numbers are treated differently from letters in this case?

Answer (score 30):

You can use Perl regex in both the find and filters if you wrap it in a forward slash.

```
from:(/(\@hp\.com$)/)
```

Will match everything from the hp.com domain.

It gets complicated very quickly because you have to escape certain characters.

Here's one I use that matches multiple address and compresses several rules down to one:

```
from:(/(^(discship|info)\@netflix\.com$)|(\@(engage|email)\.xbox\.com$)/)
Apply filter Media
```

That will label notification emails matching:

```
discship@netflix.com
info@netflix.com
ANYTHING@engage.xbox.com
ANYTHING@email.xbox.com
```

Comment: Good good. :) Was just a bit confused earlier (forgot about vote limits), but he certainly deserves it for revealing this - it'll be lots of filters I can combine now I've got regex power. :) If only I could properly label the filters to provide an at-a-glance explanation of what they're doing.

Comment: Has anyone been able to get this to work? I'm using Google Apps, and it doesn't seem to work in either the filter or search. The only reason it does seem to work is because google discards symbols so your query `from:(/(hp\.com$)/)` is becoming `from:@hp.com`. The reason `|` works is because it acts as the `OR` operator. @Turtle: do you have any links to documentation of the feature?

Comment: @Senseful: I don't have any documentation at hand, but I've been using it for several months (30+ or so). I think I remember seeing it on a site like Lifehacker or ArsTechnica as a user-submitted tip. I tried it on my Google Apps account and it worked as expected. I know, "It works for me" isn't helpful, but it's all I've got. Another example that may shed more light is this one: `from:twitter.com -from:(/(^twitter-follow-.*twitter\.com$)/)` That matches (recent) messages from twitter.com, but leaves off "new follower" notifications. What's an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Turtle: does `from:(/tw.*/)` work for you to get the messages from `twitter.com`?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Tested on both Gmail and Google Apps.

Comment: I am not able to get this to work either.

Comment: @StefanLasiewski @Senseful @CoatedMoose I just tested this in both Gmail and Google Apps and it worked perfectly. Be sure to enter your search string in the main search field, not the labeled fields in the drop-down menu. For instance, I edited an existing filter, pasted in a regex search string, and clicked 'Continue.' The result was that the main search string was populated with a string beginning `from:(from:(…` If you are still unable to get this working, please post an example of a search string you tried. Getting the syntax right is very important.

Comment: I take it back. It does work. I just tried to search for 6 web & database hosts, and it works for me: `from:(/\@web1|web2|webdev|db1|db2|dbdev\.example\.org$/)`

Comment: Does this work at all in the body? Doesn't seem to. Seems odd that there is no way to do this at least in a filter...

Comment: It seems to work for `from:`, more or less.  It does not seem to work for `subject:` AFAICT.

Comment: @StefanLasiewski I'm curious if you still feel that you can use perl regex for searching... I'm not seeing anything in your example "Regex" except alternation - if there is regex support, you should be able to get some of those results back with a wildcard-esque search -- I'll suggest you search for `from:(/[^ ]+bdev/)` which I believe in regex should match `webdev` and `dbdev` but not `bdev` -- does this work for you? A similar situation (searching for `from:(/jocke[^ ]+/)` returns 0 results, while searching either `from:(/jockey[^ ]+/)` OR `from:jockey` return several results (identical)

Comment: @Turtle I'm not so sure that is a valid test of "regex" working or not... if you have time, please see if `from:twitter -from:follow` and see if that works to return the same results as your carefully crafted filter query --- I believe your filter (and my "successes" above) can be easily explained by Gmail stripping out all punctuation and searching for the text strings, within the "from:" area (?)

Comment: This is misleading.  The only regex-like special characters that are respected by Gmail search are parentheses (for grouping) and the pipe ('OR' operator). @ToddProuty This example works because all the other symbols/punct serve as term separators, no different from spaces. Here is another example that works: `from:(/($(engage|email)\.\/xbox^com)/)`.

Comment: cannot make this work

Comment: Does not work. This answer should be voted way down. I tried `^n.*e@gmail.com$` and it did not work. Other commenters are right about the reason. 'Tis a sad day.

Comment: Wasted some time trying to get this to work

Comment: I was trying to do a regex match across both the name and domain parts and it didn't work. My solution was to regex only the name part and match with `AND` the domain: `from:(/.*Cloud.*/ AND @google.com)`

Comment: Works for me.  I can use `from:(/.*?aws.*?@amazon\.com/)` to only show Amazon Web Services emails, for example.

Comment: does not work actually, none from the above

Comment: Actually, this works for me: 
Seems like `to:(/john\+dev.*?@mydomain\.com/)`
successfully filters all emails sent to `john+dev*@mydomain.com`, e.g. `john+dev+124@mydomain.com`, `john+dev+WHATEVER@mydomain.com`, etc

Answer (score 18):

No, it is not possible. However, it depends on what you need it for. Gmail uses a very limited form of stemming based on whole words.

For example, let's see if I can retrieve emails from `phwd.lastname@gmail.com`

`from:phwd` - works

`from:pwhd.l` - nope

`from:phw` - nope

So the closest you will get in this case is if the person was nice enough to cut their first name and last name by the period.

so `phwdlastname@gmail.com` will result in all of the above searches not working.

But say I was nice to fill out my contact information and have my display name as "phwd lastname" then I can at least retrieve it this way

```
from:"phwd"

from:"phwd lastname"
```

It sucks but at least we have [Gmail Ninjas](http://www.google.com/mail/help/tips.html#master).

Comment: [This page](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=782335) has some info.

Comment: I wrote a [detailed blog post](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/07/how-gmail-filter-email-matching-works.html) about this, in case anyone wants more information.

Answer (score 16):

According [to Berkeley Lab Commons:](https://web.archive.org/web/20170117110725/https://commons.lbl.gov/display/google/Gmail+workarounds+for+sub-string+(partial+word)+search)

> Gmail search does not implement
> sub-string, partial word, wildcard, or
> regular expression searching.

Your only alternative is narrowing things down with Advanced Search or trying multiple, simultaneous options in the search box

Comment: +1 thanks Ivo for that, sometimes I have some misspelled words in emails and was hoping for some solutions for this. I will leave the question open for another day in case someone come with a work around solution for this

Comment: How funny! I work at Berkeley Lab and I was an early adopter for the Berkeley Lab Google Apps implementation, and I was part of the discussion behind that FAQ. I have a slightly different take. See my answer below.

Comment: The link now seems broken

Answer (score 6):

Wildcards are [not officially supported in Gmail](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=7190), even if they are [supported in Google Search](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136861).

That said, I have been using wildcards to match hostnames and subject lines, and I have been doing this for 5+ years. However, since wildcards are an unsupported feature, the behaviour changes from time to time. Filters that once worked will stop working after Google changes Gmail. In addition, filters used with Gmail in Google Apps may work differently then filters in standard Gmail (outside of Google Apps).

The following examples work for me in Gmail for Google Apps.

For example, until Oct 2012 I was able to use the following search to match emails sent with the from line of "example@example.org" or "example@*.example.org" (where the latter was an email sent directly from root@host.example.org, for example).

```
from:(example@example.org OR example@*.example.org)
```

But in October 2012 this filter suddenly broke. But now I can use the following search with the same results:

```
from:example*example.org
```

Also, I can use a wildcard in the subject line. The following filter will match emails with a subject like: `[jefferson-school-pta] Important information from school principal`:

```
subject:(jefferson-*)
```

Comment: As per my answer, I believe that searching for **subject:(jefferson-*)** is the same as searching for **subject:jefferson** so any apparent success with wildcards is a red herring.

Comment: Perhaps the algorithm has changed, but at the time of my email, `subject:(jefferson-*)` and `subject:jefferson` would return different results. ``subject:jefferson` would not match `jefferson-school-pta`.

Answer (score 3):

A bit easier, just write the following in the search box:

```
from: (*@mysite.com)
```

Comment: While this is correct for full pre-domain searches, it isn't a true wildcard meaning that `wordpress@domain.com` wouldn't get found from a search like `from:(word*@domain.com`).

Comment: As per my answer, I believe the * and @ do not have the intended (or any) effect.  So this search will match against everything you expected it to, **and** potentially against some extra stuff.

Comment: `from:(*@aliexpress.com)` matches an email from `transaction@notice.aliexpress.com` so it does not really work nowadays

Answer (score 3):

I know it's not the most straightforward solution, but with **Mozilla Thunderbird** asterisk wildcard will work. For example, searching *top* will find anything containing partially or totally that string, for example, Stop or TopGun.

https://commons.lbl.gov/display/google/Gmail+workarounds+for+sub-string+(partial+word)+search

Comment: this should be the accepted answer... it's a shame that still in 2022 Google didn't implemented wildcard search!

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

The search in Gmail does not allow substring search.

Comment: Adding a link to backup your claim will help.