# Filtering based on multiple labels in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I have some labels which are logically related. I'd like to filter those and put them in a second inbox by enabling multiple inbox lab feature. Is there a possible way to do that?

Additional info: All the labels start with "AJ"

Answer (score 11):

You have two choices:

1. `label:AJ-Label-1 label:AJ-Label-2`
2. `label:AJ-Label-1 OR label:AJ-Label-2`

The first option will perform an AND search, meaning the email must have both labels applied to it. The second option performs an OR search which will match if any of the labels are applied to a message.

The fact that both start with `AJ` unfortunately doesn't help since [labels can't be searched via stemming](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2834/is-there-a-way-to-search-labels-based-on-stemming-in-gmail). You must list both of them explicitly in your query.

Tip: To make it easier to create queries, you should use the search box in Gmail which provides code completion, and then copy and paste the query into the Multiple Inboxes settings.

Note: If your labels contain spaces, replace the space with the `-` character.

Comment: Just realized "OR" has to be uppercase; "or" won't work.

Comment: It doesn't seem that the first choice works anymore...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gmail labs](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/labs)'s Nested Labels feature.

The description copied from labs page

> Manage your email by sorting it into
>   a hierarchy of labels. Add slashes (/)
>   to label names to express inheritance.
>   For example, if you want a Home label
>   with two child labels named Kids and
>   Shopping, create the three following
>   labels: Home, Home/Kids and
>   Home/Shopping.