# Can I have auto-response to only emails that has only one sender?

Tags: gmail

Can I only send a vacation response to the only emails that are specific to me.

Case 1: there is only one senders and no CCs -> send auto response

Case 2: sender has sent me, and to someone else(CCs) as well -> dont send auto response.

Comment: The Vacation Responder won't work that way, but you might be able to do something with Canned Responses and the solution(s) here: [How can I set a Gmail filter that finds email sent “only to me”?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/5108/354)