# Can I get a list of "+" addresses I've used in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wildcard search in gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2433/wildcard-search-in-gmail)

Gmail has this very nice "+" feature that I actually use quite a lot. I use it to easily filter my mail and check if my address is being passed along.
So for example, if I go to a conference, they always want an e-mail address. I just use

> myemail+conferencename@gmail.com

and setup a filter in Gmail to filter all messages send to this address and label it.

Now, I've used this feature so often, that I don't really have an overview anymore of all the +'s I've used so far (yes, because occasionally I forget to setup the filter :/ )
I've tried to search for:

```
to: myemail+*  
to: "myemail+"*
```

and lots of different variations, but no success so far.

Comment: Just a clarification: The "+address" feature is not specifically a Gmail feature. It has been part of the e-mail spec since before the Web. It's just that not all e-mail clients have supported it.

Comment: I've poured over the advanced search docs and tried multiple different things, and it seems to me that you're not going to be able to do what you want with Gmail as it currently exists. Whether you could use a third-party e-mail client and do this I really don't know, but I suspect that it's your best option.

Comment: I was just looking for a solution to the same problem and found a solution at http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/07/how-gmail-filter-email-matching-works.html:
You must use negation to match all email sent to plus addresses: To filter on all plus addresses [...], you should use the query john.smith@gmail.com -"john smith gmail com". The first part of the query will match any plus addresses you have. The second will remove all those that don't have the words in the exact order. For example, john.smith+foo@gmail.com will not match since it has the word foo in between the other words. @RoelF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is basically already answered by [Wildcard search in Gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2433/wildcard-search-in-gmail)

Without any kind of wildcard or regex support, it doesn't seem possible.