# Filter blank emails

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I get a lot of system alerts related blank mails. The custom scripts send empty mails when there is no issue found on the server.

How do I filter such mail? I know how to filter using "From" and "to" fields. I need to know if there is anything in the contents tag.

Comment: Can you have them custom script add some phrase such as Nothing significant to report.

Answer (score -1):

All of the available search operators are listed in [GMail advanced search help](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=7190). There's no standard wildcard selector to put into `Doesn't have` but according to [a question about wildcards](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/2433/15875) you can use Perl RegEx for query. This way, you need to construct a query that searches for the absence of any character in the body.

[image]

[image]

Comment: And how do you check if the body of the mail is empty?

Comment: You check with the parameters that aren't empty, such as `From` and `Subject`.

Comment: The OP stated that the script sends empty emails, so how do you check for this situation—if an email’s body is empty or not? That is the OP’s question.

Comment: @Alex: See the edits.