# Stopping spam emails in Gmail by pattern

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

There is a this spammer with maybe a 100+ fake emails. The pattern is as follows:
`jobsnext130@yahoo.in`, `jobsnext131@yahoo.in` and so on. Essentially, `jobsnext(a number)@yahoo.in`

I have tried to stop this by marking it as spam but that cannot stop the rest in the pattern. I have already reported spam from over 30 emails in the list but they just keep coming.

Is there a way (in Gmail) to stop mails from `jobsnext%anything%@yahoo.in`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a script to print the emails in pattern. 
Advanced search in Gmail accepts 50emails at a time

```
for($i=100;$i<=150;$i++)
{
echo "jobsnext".($i)."@yahoo.in|";
}
```

Output will be like
`jobsnext100@yahoo.in|jobsnext101@yahoo.in|jobsnext102@yahoo.in|jobsnext103...`

Made two filters 50+50. And send them all to trash

Answer (score 7):

[Gmail uses Perl regex](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2433/wildcard-search-in-gmail) for searching. I think this string should do it.

`from:(/jobsnext((.)*\@yahoo\.in$)/)`

If you replace the dot with `\d`, you would only include digits, now it includes every possible string after the `jobsnext`.

Comment: Where can you edit the filter?

Comment: Make your own filter and then slap a label on all the emails trapped by the filter. You can even have the filter have them skip the inbox. Once you are confident that the filter works without false positives you can even be bold enough to delete them.

Comment: @steven
The wild cards you mentioned returned no results
Can you point me to the source and post a screenshot showing that it works

Comment: However, this gave the right result for a particular email can you please correct it..
`from:(/(jobsnext171)(\@yahoo\.in$)/)`

Comment: @AbhijithVenkata My e-mail address is stevenroose@gmail.com and I did this search, returning all messages I have sent: http://screencloud.net/v/v10L

Comment: `from:(/jobsnext171((.)*\@yahoo\.in$)/)`
This is giving the desired output. Are numericals the problem?

Comment: That shouldn't be. A `.` in regex stands for all possible characters.

Comment: If its not too much to ask, can you please check your mail with email with numbers
like check the expression for steven122@gmail.com

Comment: The point is that I have no such addresses in my inbox. I'll try to send myself some spam and try the `subject:` search field.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4790/discussion-between-abhijith-venkata-and-steven-roose)

Comment: AFAIK you _cannot_ use regular expressions directly within Gmail? And this does not seem to work for me. Where did you read this? However, with the help of Google Docs you can apparently set up a spreadsheet to search your Gmail with a regexp, but this doesn't help you in setting up a filter. http://www.labnol.org/internet/advanced-gmail-search/21623/

Comment: I found it here, and for me it works for letters, for some reason not for numbers. http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2433/wildcard-search-in-gmail

Answer (score -1):

you might find his ip from his emails maybe and try to take him down by putting his ip on bans list for spammers. I think you can go to settings of ur email nd enter that ip there... hopefully it will stop. or google it to block his ip.

Comment: Firstly, I don't think gmail provides the feature to block email using the sender's ip.

Secondly, the sender server might be a legit large scale server which hosts a lot of no spamming websites and i will be blocking them all. OR the server can have a dynamic ip