# Training Gmail Spam filter

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

How many times do I have to *Report Spam* from a mail address to block all the mails from that address or send them all to spam? I have reported an email for spam about 7 times but Gmail shows new mails from that address as *Important*.

Answer (score 3):

Gmail's spam filters aren't simply based on the Senders email address. And it is also dependent on other users flagging similar emails as spam. Gmail determines that a particular email is spam by seeing how the global gmail community sees that email.

If all this spam / unwanted messages are coming from a single email address then *you* can set up a filter to send all email from that sender to spam. Filters affect just *your* email account.

Comment: Actually the spammer is using a series of email address. Here's the related thread

http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30909/stopping-spam-emails-in-gmail-by-pattern

Answer (score 0):

Are those mail ids in your addressbook? If then, remove those emails from your addressbook first.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer and possibly offer steps for the OP to check on what you're asking? Also helpful would be Google FAQ/Help post information regarding marking something as spam.