# An email black list in Gmail

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stopping spam emails in Gmail by pattern](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30909/stopping-spam-emails-in-gmail-by-pattern)

I have a good number of email addresses (around 200) which are spamming me to no end.

Can I make a black list and not receive any mails from these addresses?

Essentially I want a feature similar to *Reject List* on my phone. If I add a number to my reject list, all the calls and message from that number with be rejected.

*Filters don't allow 200 emails at a time; please don't suggest that.*

Comment: Sorry, but Filters are the only way to directly affect incoming messages in Gmail. [Google Operating System devised a way to do it without _too_ much pain](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2006/08/create-email-blacklist-in-gmail.html). Your other options are to use something besides Gmail.

Answer (score 4):

Keep marking it as spam. Over a period, Google will deliver such messages to spam folder, especially if those are identified as spam by others as well.

Comment: Not an efficient way. I have marked it as spam a lot of times in vain. Please refer [This thread](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31148/training-gmail-spam-filter)