# Why does search in Google Mail not find some substrings but others work?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

Today I saw a very strange behavior when searching in Google Mail.
I was looking for an eMail which contained an IP: `192.168.100.150`.

I couldn't remember exactly what it was, but I knew the first three parts, so I was searching for `192.168.100` and did not get any results.

After several tries, I tested `192.168` and and suddenly got several results, including the IP I was looking for.

The IP is part of a URL like follows: `https://192.168.100.150/SOMEPATH/`

Summary:

Searching for `192.168.100` did **not** work.

Searching for `192.168` or `192.168.100.150` **worked fine**.

Can someone explain this behavior to me?

Comment: Just now. Doesn't work.

Comment: Could this be related to these other gmail search fails? 
http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/99283/gmail-search-sometimes-fails-when-text-looks-like-a-date 
http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/98346/why-does-gmail-search-fail-on-this-message

Comment: It could also have something to do with the way that Gmail search uses "tokens" (at least according to this answer: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/58592/108464 )

Comment: Probably it is part of the answer, but doesn't really fit it. I specifically didn't understand why the first did not work, while others worked. And the token based system should allow both to work.

Comment: Btw: I can still reproduce this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Gmail interprets searches for something, that looks like a number, as a search for that number, and searches for strings as searches for complete words.

Accordingly, your search for '192.168' is interpreted as a search for the number 192 decimal point 168.

And your search for '192.168.100.150' is interpreted as a search for the word '192.168.100.150'.

Because '192.168.100' is not a valid number format, since it has 2 decimal points, it is considered a search for a word, and because (don't ask me why - my best guess would be, that google is indexing *exact* words and numbers and returns results from that index, and is thus simply not able to actually perform a full-text substring search for that reason) google is not able to search for substrings of words, it does not find your '192.168.100.150'.

This behavior is hinted by the comment on "Search operators you can use with Gmail" (https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) --> "Note: When using numbers as part of your query, a space or a dash (-) will separate a number while a dot (.) will be a decimal. For example, 01.2047-100 is considered 2 numbers: 01.2047 and 100."

Comment: Your answer makes a lot of sense.Thanks for digging that up and answering it.
For me this makes enough sense to accept the answer.