# Get rid of Russian junk from my Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, spam-prevention

For a while now, the spam folder in my Gmail everyday gets simply flooded with Russian-speaking / Russian-written junk e-mails.

How can I get rid of it? Is there any filter in Gmail, that let me target specific language, alphabet (Cyrylic) or maybe specific sender's domain (`.ru` and `.su`)?

Comment: If it’s already in your spam folder, what’s the problem? You should not even see those emails.

Comment: I don't know, how you're using spam folder in Gmail, but I **do** watch its contents from time to time. Ever heard `false positive` term? I don't know how many e-mails incorrectly marked as spam I have "ressurrected" from that folder for past five years of using Gmail. Having this folder flooded with Russian junk makes such browsing much harder. It is quite difference, if you have 10 spams per day versus if you have 15 spams per hour, right?

Comment: BTW: You have edited my question and removed my refference to Russian invasion, but you have left footnote explaining it in place. Any reason for that? Seems useless and non-sense as for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a filter, if you can find a search that will hit only the emails you want, and have all matching messages deleted? Or at least "never send to spam" but instead moved to a special folder if you want to review them too.

I thought that maybe some **characters** that never show up in your language like ф peraps? But apparently Gmail doesn't search like that, here's a good overview from [another answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/58592):

> The Gmail search functionality works based on what I would describe as tokens. A token is any sequence of alphanumeric characters separated by a space or by other non-alphanumeric characters such as underscore, full stop (period), "@", dash, etc.. So in peter.ford23@example.com there are 4 tokens: "peter", "ford23", "example" and "com".
>
> Wildcards within tokens do not work.

So Gmail only searches by words or parts of emails. Even the `.` in the examples below may be unnecessary (`from:.ru` may be the same as `from:ru`)

Or something like `from:.ru` should match all messages whose from address contains .ru (I tested `from:(.com)` that matches anything.com addresses, while `from:(.co)` matches emails **containing** .co like `@yahoo.co.uk`.

There may be a combination of "tokens"/words in the `from:`, `subject:`,`body:` that might match enough messages...

---

There *used to be* a good language search, but apparently it doesn't work anymore. [This guy said](http://www.labnol.org/internet/gmail-language-filter-reduces-spam/9000/) that Gmail could search emails by language using `lang:[code]`, like `lang:ru` for Russian. More [language codes should be here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest#language-params). I don't think I have any emails like that so couldn't test, but trying `lang:en` didn't show any hits, so it looks like it's no longer available.

---

Or, you could try a filter for the "false positive" spam you frequently see and keep those out of the spam folder, maybe search for your name or something unique? That would probably result in a lot of spam not in the spam folder though.

Comment: This sounds like a perfect answer. Let me test it for a few days, but I'm pretty sure, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Even if the `lang:` codes don't work anymore, a combination of a few other searches might. Like `from:` and some characters, could use `(a or b or c)`, gmail can do some complicated bracket `and` / `or` searches

Comment: Nope, this does not work. `lang:` does not work, as you suggested and I tried (as search criteria): `in:anywhere from:(к or т or л or н or т or и)`, `in:anywhere from:(к т л н т и)` or `in:anywhere from:(ктлнти)` to catch any e-mail, that has Cyrylic letters in sender's name. No effect. It was not able to find any of Russian spam I already have in my SPAM box.

Comment: Yeah, apparently gmail won't search by character (or wildcard or parts of words), I'll update the answer a little

Comment: Why not try a number of Russian words strung together with or? If I wanted to pick out English emails, I'd use ```the or you or to or do" for example. That should catch most English emails and not many French, German, Russian etc.

Answer (score 1):

A working solution for me to get rid of all the Russian calendar invitations was to filter to the top 50 Russian words and tick "Has attachment". You can test the results if you paste this to the Gmail serach box:

```
("и"|"в"|"не"|"он"|"на"|"я"|"что"|"тот"|"быть"|"с"|"а"|"весь"|"это"|"как"|"она"|"по"|"но"|"они"|"к"|"у"|"ты"|"из"|"мы"|"за"|"вы"|"так"|"же"|"от"|"сказать"|"этот"|"который"|"мочь"|"человек"|"о"|"один"|"ещё"|"бы"|"такой"|"только"|"себя"|"своё"|"какой"|"когда"|"уже"|"для"|"вот"|"кто"|"да"|"говорить"|"год")
```

or you can add and `has:attachment` to it to get only ones with an attachment

Note that you must put the Russian words between quotes or else gmail will also find the words translated to English. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't expect emails with Cyrillic characters, I just add this line to other filters that would focus on likely spam. This represents all the Cyrillic characters in the Russian language.

```
{а б в г д е ж з и й к л м н о п р с т у ф х ц ч ш щ ъ ы ь э ю я}
```

I also apply a label "Auto Deleted" so that if in case I'll need to manually check, it would be easy to find those mails hit with this filter. You have 30 days before those auto-deleted messages are cleaned out by Gmail.

Answer (score -1):

In Gmail search for the following:

`in:spam д|ж|и`

Add other Cyrillic only letters as you desire to get the results you need.

-- edit --
Whilst I understand that this answer doesn't work for all, in my testing using Chrome on Windows 10, I do get results.

Comment: The above answer (and a comment on it) mentioned that this method does not work. If you have tested it yourself and it *does* work, please edit the existing answer to indicate that it has since become a viable solution. Thanks!