# Filter email based on Gmail plus operator, with wildcard

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, gmail-search

Due to some programming integration tests I've setup to run often, I'm receiving emails to my gmail with a plus address like so:

- matt+unittest_1
- matt+unittest_2
- matt+unittest_3

etc.

I would like to filter out email I receive to the +unittest_* addresses; however I can't seem to find the right search term. When I search for one specific plus address it finds the email; however searching the 'to' address for 'unittest' or any combination thereof does not work.

Is this possible using Gmail (well technically G Suite since it's a custom domain... but Gmail).

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Unless you can craft a search which works for you, you can't create a filter for it. Gmail search doesn't really do wildcards mixed with other texts. I would have suggested to try `to:unittest_`, but you've indicated that that doesn't work.

Comment: Related: [Wildcard search in Gmail](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/2433/354)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Gmail allows use of the wildcard (*) before and after.  Use *unitest*.  As mentioned, verify the filter works as expected with a search, then save as a filter.  I first did this unintentionally - it works!

Comment: To date, wildcard searching in Gmail is generally not supported. I feel that you've hit on something which you think is giving you the results you want, but it's only a coincidence based on the data you have. It would better if you could back this up with some documentation from Google Support.